# Java Spring boot does not allow access to api urls to admins

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have built spring boot app with spring security.
It stores user roles in db.

I have following Spring secuity config:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/restricted/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .logout(l -> l.logoutSuccessUrl("http://localhost:3000/login").permitAll())
        .cors() 
        .oauth2Login()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("http://localhost:3000/home")
            .userInfoEndpoint()
                .oidcUserService(customOidcUserService);
    return http.build();
}
```

I have also setup [swagger](https://swagger.io/) (swagger is somewhat like [postman](https://www.postman.com/)). I hit its URL, it redirected to Google login. I entered my google login and now it showed me swagger UI. On first time log in, the logged in user's email is captured in db and is given role `ROLE_USER`. I then went to DB and modified its role to `ROLE_ADMIN` and restarted the app.

I tried to access the user corresponding to my current login through swagger UI and it returned:

```
{
  "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
  "password": null,
  "roles": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "ROLE_ADMIN"
    }
  ]
}
```

So, at least it seems that swagger UI is able to correctly fetch the role as ADMIN.

Now when I try to access the restricted URLs which are listed in swagger UI as `/api/restricted/**` (e.g. `/api/restricted/user/{id}`) I am getting `HTTP 403 Forbidden` reponse despite of the fact that the currently logged in user is an `ADMIN`. Where I am making mistake?

**Update**

According to [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionRoot.html#hasRole(java.lang.String)), `hasRole()` checkes in `Authentication.getAuthorities()` and my `Authentication.getAuthorities()` did not had `ROLE_ADMIN`. But `((MyCustomUserDetails) Authentication.Principal).getAuthorities`  had `ROLE_ADMIN`. This must be because I implemented it as explained [here](https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-jwt-authentication#Implement_UserDetails_038_UserDetailsService): implementation of `UserDetails` contains `Collection authorities`. How can I make it available in `Authentication.getAuthorities()`?

Comment: And your debug logs tell you?

Comment: pls show log application. I think you config mistake

Comment: According to docs, `hasRole()` checkes in `Authentication.getAuthorities()` and my `Authentication.getAuthorities()` did not had `ROLE_ADMIN`. But `((MyCustomUserDetails) Authentication.Principal).getAuthorities`  had `ROLE_ADMIN`. This must be because I implemented it as explained [here](https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-jwt-authentication#Implement_UserDetails_038_UserDetailsService): implementation of `UserDetails` contains `Collection authorities`. How can I make it available in `Authentication.getAuthorities()`? (`hasRole` doc link added in original post in bottom update.)